# Parse html page source with libcurl and C

Tags: c, parsing, function, libcurl

How can I print the source of a webpage, specified in curl_easy_setopt, without html tags? So, printing only the text in the source?

Comment: curl is an HTTP interaction library. I don't think it has anything to do with parsing HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curl/libcurl is just for fetching the HTML page. To extract information from it, you need other tools.

The most general solution is to use a HTML parser. A good one in C is [HTMLparser from libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).